# Бинарное дерево, не выводиться

Tags: c

Проблема с main, после ввода значений дерева, программа просто заканчивает работу.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
 
typedef struct tree
{
    int key;
    struct tree* left;
    struct tree* right;
    struct tree* parent;
} node;
node* create(node* root, int key)
{
    // Выделение памяти под корень дерева
    node* tmp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    // Присваивание значения ключу
    tmp->key = key;
    // Присваивание указателю на родителя значения NULL
    tmp->parent = NULL;
    // Присваивание указателю на левое и правое поддерево значения NULL
    tmp->left = tmp->right = NULL;
    root = tmp;
    return root;
}
node* add(node* root, int key)
{
    node* root2 = root, * root3 = NULL;
    // Выделение памяти под узел дерева
    node* tmp =(node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    // Присваивание значения ключу
    tmp->key = key;
    /* Поиск нужной позиции для вставки /
    while (root2 != NULL)
    {
        root3 = root2;
        if (key < root2->key)
            root2 = root2->left;
        else
            root2 = root2->right;
    }
    /* Присваивание указателю на родителя значения указателя root3
    (указатель root3 был найден выше) */
    tmp->parent = root3;
    // Присваивание указателю на левое и правое поддерево значения NULL
    tmp->left = NULL;
    tmp->right = NULL;
    /* Вставляем узел в дерево (руководствуемся правилом
    вставки элементов, см. начало статьи, пункт 3) */
    if (key < root3->key) root3->left = tmp;
    else root3->right = tmp;
    return root;
}
node* search(node* root, int key)
{
    // Если дерево пусто или ключ корня равен искомому ключу, то возвращается указатель на корень
    if ((root == NULL) || (root->key = key))
        return root;
    // Поиск нужного узла
    if (key < root->key)
        return search(root->left, key);
    else return search(root->right, key);
}
node* min(node* root)
{
    node* l = root;
    while (l->left != NULL)
        l = l->left;
    return l;
}// Минимальный элемент дерева
node* max(node* root)
{
    node* r = root;
    while (r->right != NULL)
        r = r->right;
    return r;
}// Максимальный элемент дерева
node* succ(node* root)
{
    node* p = root, * l = NULL;
    // Если есть правое поддерево, то ищем минимальный элемент в этом поддереве
    if (p->right != NULL)
        return min(p->right);
    /* Правое дерево пусто, идем по родителям до тех пор,
    пока не найдем родителя, для которого наше поддерево левое */
    l = p->parent;
    while ((l != NULL) && (p == l->right))
    {
        p = l;
        l = l->parent;
    }
    return l;
}
node* deletee(node* root, int key)
{
    // Поиск удаляемого узла по ключу
    node* p = root, * l = NULL, * m = NULL;
    l = search(root, key);
    // 1 случай
    if ((l->left == NULL) && (l->right == NULL))
    {
        m = l->parent;
        if (l == m->right) m->right == NULL;
        else m->left == NULL;
        free(l);
    }
    // 2 случай, 1 вариант - поддерево справа
    if ((l->left == NULL) && (l->right != NULL))
    {
        m = l->parent;
        if (l == m->right) m->right == l->right;
        else m->left == l->right;
        free(l);
    }
    // 2 случай, 2 вариант - поддерево слева
    if ((l->left != NULL) && (l->right == NULL))
    {
        m = l->parent;
        if (l == m->right) m->right == l->left;
        else m->left == l->left;
        free(l);
    }
    // 3 случай
    if ((l->left != NULL) && (l->right != NULL))
    {
        m = succ(l);
        l->key = m->key;
        if (m->right == NULL)
            m->parent->left = NULL;
        else m->parent->left = m->right;
        free(m);
    }
    return root;
}
void preorder(node* root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    if (root->key)
        printf("%d ", root->key);
    preorder(root->left);
    preorder(root->right);
}
void postorder(node* root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    postorder(root->left);
    postorder(root->right);
    if (root->key)
        printf("%d ", root->key);
}
void inorder(node* root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    inorder(root->left);
    if (root->key)
        printf("%d ", root->key);
    inorder(root->right);
}
int main() {
    int key;
    struct tree* root;
    root = NULL;
    
    printf("wpisz\n");
    do {
        scanf("%d", &key);
        if (isalnum(key))
            root = add(root, key);
    } while (key != 0);
    create(root, key);
    search(root, key);
    preorder(root);
    postorder(root);
    inorder(root);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: цикл `while (root2 != NULL)` закомментировали. увидели? `m->right == NULL;` - это сравнение, а не присваивание значения.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
int main() {
    int key;
    struct tree* root;
    root = NULL;
    
    printf("wpisz\n");
    do {
        scanf("%d", &key);
        if (isalnum(key))
            root = add(root, key);
    } while (key != 0);
    create(root, key);
    search(root, key);
    preorder(root);
    postorder(root);
    inorder(root);
 
    system("pause");
}
```

И наверху кода напиши #include

Может быть, это выводится но программа моментально завершает работу ну и вот
Я  не full кодер на C++

Comment: Точнее #include <iostream> наверху напиши

Comment: Увы ничего не получилось( Может проблема в коде? Я писал его с помощью примеров с сайтов про бин деревья

Comment: Вы тэг `c` увидели? Какой `iostream`?!